# $\lambda_k \to 0$ implies $T$ is compact?

Tags: functional-analysis, operator-theory, hilbert-spaces, normed-spaces

I am doing an exercise which asks to show that if $\{\varphi_k\}$ is an orthonormal basis in a Hilbert space with $T$ a bounded operator satisfying $T\varphi_k = \lambda_k \varphi_k$, then $\lambda_k \to 0$ implies that $T$ is compact. Now I will be done if I can show that $TP_n \to T$ in norm for $P_n$ is a compact operator. Here $P_n$ is the orthogonal projection onto the linear span $\{\varphi_1\ldots,\varphi_n\}$.

However the hint given is that $\lambda_k\to 0$ already implies this. Why is this so? I guess if I can understand why $||T|| = \sup_k |\lambda_k|$ then I would be done. For I believe $||P_nT - T|| = \sup_{k\geq n} |\lambda_k|$ and then $\lim_{n\to \infty} ||P_nT - T|| = \limsup_{n\to \infty} |\lambda_n| = 0.$

> > **My question is:** Why is $||T|| = \sup_{k} |\lambda_k|$?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Any vector $x$ can be expanded in the orthonormal basis as $x = \sum_k x_k \varphi_k$, and any vector expressed in such a way has norm given by $\Vert x \Vert^2 = \sum_k |x_k|^2$. Thus $$ \Vert T(x)  \Vert^2 = \Vert  \sum_k  x_k T(\varphi_k) \Vert^2  =  \Vert \sum_k x_k\lambda_k \varphi_k\Vert^2 \\= \sum_k |x_k \lambda_k|^2  \le \sum_k\sup_j|\lambda_j|^2x_k^2 = \sup_k|\lambda_k|^2 \lVert x \rVert^2.$$

This shows $\Vert T \Vert \le \sup_k |\lambda_k|$. For the other direction, note that $\Vert T(\varphi_k)\Vert= \Vert \lambda_k \varphi_k \Vert = |\lambda_k|$ implies $\Vert T\Vert\ge |\lambda_k|$ for every $k$; i.e. $\Vert T\Vert \ge \sup_k |\lambda_k|$.

Comment: @Grothendieck: $\Vert T \Vert$ is the supremum of $\Vert T(x) \Vert$ over normalized $x$; so in particular it is at least $\Vert T(\varphi_k) \Vert$ since $\varphi_k$ has length $1$.

Comment: Ah ok, I forgot that $\varphi_k$ had norm $1$ :D Thanks for your answer.